# Python: What is the use of eval function

Tags: python, python-3.x, eval, python-3.6

As I read from the documentation eval() function is used to evaluate an Expression.

But Python is doing that by default right. I mean

```
>>> x=10
>>> x+2
12
>>> eval('x+2')
12
>>>
```

So when I enter `x+2` python evaluated/interpreted that statement, so why again using eval() function here.

And I thought using it in a python program may cause some difference so I tried that as well.

```
x=10
x=x+12
print(x)
print(eval('x+13'))
print(x+13)
```

With output as

```
22
35
35
```

So `print(x+13)` and `print(eval('x+13'))` are printing same results and I believe doing same action internally.

Am I missing any best or dedicated use cases of `eval()` function in Python ? Or its just what I understand ?

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: You may be getting the input from somewhere else (from a user, from another program etc.). You cannot just execute them like you would execute `x+2`. Not all programs run in the interactive interpreter.

Comment: @ayhan, can you give me one example ?

Comment: `eval(input('please enter an arithmetic expression: '))` would return 5 if the user enters `2+3` for example. The user normally doesn't have access to the program so they can only supply inputs.